# Terminal commands show there is no non-free software on the system

Tags: linux, dpkg, licenses, free-software

`vrms` [1] returns "No non-free or contrib packages installed on Hostname!  rms would be proud." and `dpkg-query -W -f='${Section}\t${Package}\n' | grep ^non-free` [2]  returns nothing on the terminal.

However, after running

```
packages=`dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/:amd64//'`
for package in $packages; do echo "<<< $package >>> "; cat /usr/share/doc/$package/copyright; done > ./licenses
```

I see an output as following, which says there is no license for some packages:

```
cat: /usr/share/doc/libddccontrol0/copyright: No such file or directory
cat: /usr/share/doc/linux-image-4.19.0-12-amd64/copyright: No such file or directory
cat: /usr/share/doc/live-tools/copyright: No such file or directory
cat: /usr/share/doc/rsync/copyright: No such file or directory
cat: /usr/share/doc/user-setup/copyright: No such file or directory
```

How [1] and [2] commands decide they are also free in this case?

Comment: Note `:amd64` added to the package names in each of those pathnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall`

If same packages in the output are returned, purge them with `apt-get purge PACKAGENAME`

And repeat your steps over again

Answer (score 1):

The first command doesn't check the package license, it only checks from which repository is the package installed and outputs packages installed from the [non-free repository](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive#s-non-free).

Second command checks wrong paths for the license files, it shouldn't include the architecture suffix -- e.g. `/usr/share/doc/binutils-common/copyright` for the `binutils-common` package, not `/usr/share/doc/binutils-common:amd64/copyright` (see [file list](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/binutils-common/filelist) for binutils-common amd64 package).

Comment: I added sed command to remove the suffix and most of the output disappeared. Can you look edit?